# Unable to run NextJS with npm run build

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, digital-ocean

I recently deployed a react static app on my digitalocean server. All I did was show the root directory of the build file in the Nginx config file. And it's running well.

Now I am trying to host a NextJS app on my server. I showed the root directory `root /var/www/html/NextJSTestApp/.next` I even tried with `root /var/www/html/NextJSTestApp/node_modules`
When I am running the `npm run build` the build is done then I tried to reach my server it's showing "502 Bad Gateway"

But when I am running `npm start`
[site image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKJj6.png)
The app is showing

What I can do to run it all the time? I am using digitalocean droplet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution. To run this project background I used pm2.

- `sudo npm install -g pm2`
  Then gone to my project folder `cd website/`

`pm2 start --name=website npm -- start`

then `pm2 startup systemd`

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.coderrocketfuel.com/article/how-to-deploy-a-next-js-website-to-a-digital-ocean-server)

Answer (score 0):

When running NextJS as a node application (e.g. next start), you need to set nginx to use `proxy_pass` instead of pointing it to a root directory (omit root directive).

Example nginx location block

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.key;

    location / {

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; //your next app
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Manually running `next start` does not persist the process once you close the terminal or leave the bash. In order to let it run in the background, you may use && at the end of start command (next start &&) or create a systemd file (recommended).

Second, Once you are done with a nextJs running on background, you can go ahead and setup a proxy pass to your web server(nginx, apache ...)